# WP7 - Dynamic information request to a server based on information entered by the user

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, httprequest

This time, i come here just to see some opinios/view points.

I have a 'autocomplete' component that get from my server, the cities names of my country. At each city name typed on this component, it should go to my server a get some info.

Actually, how am I doing it?

At each letter typed on this component, it requests a list of cities that starts with this letter.
Obviously, that is no a good way to do it, because each request based just on a letter give me very similar lists.

Do you can think a better way to do it?

What is a better way? Do not make unecessary requests.

Answer (score 1):

You could either preload all the city names locally (a country with 10,000 cities having an average name length of 11 bytes [10 single-byte characters + NUL] would require not much more than 110KB of space, depending on the method of storage [possibly something closer to 200KB?], so if you're okay with a [quite possibly very] small delay when loading the page and aren't worrying much about phone data limits, I'd suggest this), or you could have the city names be cached on the local machine, so while unique key combinations will result in server fetches, a repeated key combination in a later component will not.

I'm not really experienced with this aspect of programming, though, so I'm probably not the best person to give this sort of advice.